# Inconsistent results with Service Broker in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using script from [rusanu.com](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-to-a-background-procedure/) to execute stored procedures with parameters asynchronously.

I have around 20-30 stored procedures and these stored procedures store the results based on data passed to them in a global temporary table.

But I am getting greatly inconsistent results for exactly the same data. The script works all right otherwise.

Are there any issues as such that may lead to this behavior ?

**Edit 1:**  `dbo.Match` procedure --accessed commonly by those 20-30 procedures.

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[MATCH]
@parameterFromUser  nvarchar(30),
@ColumnnName nvarchar(30) ,
@constantval float(2),
@checkbool int
As 
Begin
declare @maxim int = 0 
declare @Matches table
(
RowId int not null primary key ,
PercentMatch decimal(8,3) not null,
Percentage decimal(18, 4)
)
declare @Temp table
(
[Row] int,
VarLength int,
Counts int,
MaxMatch int
)
declare @tempint int = Len(@parameterFromUser), @counter int = 1, @counterOuter int = 1
while(@counterOuter <= @tempint)
begin
set @counter = @counterOuter 
while(@counter <= @tempint)
Begin
if @checkbool = 0
begin

Insert into @Temp([Row], Counts, VarLength) 
select  Rowid, (@counter - @counterOuter) + 1, 
CASE WHEN @ColumnnName = 'firstname' THEN LEN(FirstName)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'middlename' THEN LEN(middlename)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'lastname' THEN LEN(LastName)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'State' THEN LEN([State])
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'City' THEN LEN(City)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'StreetName' THEN LEN(StreetName)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'StreetType' THEN LEN(StreetType)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'patientnickname' THEN LEN(patientnickname)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'patientsMaidenlastname' THEN LEN(patientsMaidenlastname)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'fathersFirstName' THEN LEN(fathersFirstName)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'fatherslastname' THEN LEN(fatherslastname)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'motherslastname' THEN LEN(motherslastname)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'motherslastname' THEN LEN(motherslastname)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'mothersMaidenlastname' THEN LEN(mothersMaidenlastname)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'citizenship' THEN LEN(citizenship)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'nationality' THEN LEN(nationality)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'Ethnicity' THEN LEN(Ethnicity)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'race' THEN LEN(race)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'religion' THEN LEN(religion)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'primarylanguage' THEN LEN(primarylanguage)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'patientmrn' THEN LEN(patientmrn)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'hospitalname' THEN LEN(hospitalname)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'Medicaidid' THEN LEN(Medicaidid)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'pcpnpi' THEN LEN(pcpnpi)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'phonenumber' THEN LEN(phonenumber)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'email' THEN LEN(email)


End
from Patients where 
(case when @ColumnnName = 'firstname' then firstname 
            when @ColumnnName = 'middlename' then middlename 
            when @ColumnnName = 'lastname' then lastname 
            when @ColumnnName = 'State' then [State] 
            when @ColumnnName = 'City' then City 
            when @ColumnnName = 'StreetName' then StreetName 
            when @ColumnnName = 'StreetType' then StreetType 
            when @ColumnnName = 'patientnickname' then patientnickname
            when @ColumnnName = 'patientsMaidenlastname' then patientsMaidenlastname
            when @ColumnnName = 'fathersFirstName' then fathersFirstName
            when @ColumnnName = 'fatherslastname' then fatherslastname
            when @ColumnnName = 'mothersfirstname' then mothersfirstname
            when @ColumnnName = 'motherslastname' then motherslastname
            when @ColumnnName = 'mothersMaidenlastname' then mothersMaidenlastname
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'citizenship' THEN citizenship
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'nationality' THEN nationality
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'Ethnicity' THEN Ethnicity
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'race' THEN race
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'religion' THEN religion
           WHEN @ColumnnName = 'primarylanguage' THEN primarylanguage
           WHEN @ColumnnName = 'patientmrn' THEN patientmrn
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'hospitalname' THEN hospitalname
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'Medicaidid' THEN Medicaidid
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'pcpnpi' THEN pcpnpi
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'phonenumber' THEN phonenumber
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'email' THEN email





            end) LIKE + '%' + SUBSTRING(@parameterFromUser, @counterOuter, @counter) + '%' 
end
else if @checkbool = 1
begin

Insert into @Temp([Row], Counts, VarLength) 
select  p.Rowid, (@counter - @counterOuter) + 1, 
CASE WHEN @ColumnnName = 'firstname' THEN LEN(FirstName)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'middlename' THEN LEN(middlename)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'lastname' THEN LEN(LastName)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'State' THEN LEN([State])
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'City' THEN LEN(City)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'StreetName' THEN LEN(StreetName)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'StreetType' THEN LEN(StreetType)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'patientnickname' THEN LEN(patientnickname)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'patientsMaidenlastname' THEN LEN(patientsMaidenlastname)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'fathersFirstName' THEN LEN(fathersFirstName)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'fatherslastname' THEN LEN(fatherslastname)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'motherslastname' THEN LEN(motherslastname)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'motherslastname' THEN LEN(motherslastname)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'mothersMaidenlastname' THEN LEN(mothersMaidenlastname)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'citizenship' THEN LEN(citizenship)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'nationality' THEN LEN(nationality)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'Ethnicity' THEN LEN(Ethnicity)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'race' THEN LEN(race)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'religion' THEN LEN(religion)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'primarylanguage' THEN LEN(primarylanguage)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'patientmrn' THEN LEN(patientmrn)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'hospitalname' THEN LEN(hospitalname)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'Medicaidid' THEN LEN(Medicaidid)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'pcpnpi' THEN LEN(pcpnpi)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'phonenumber' THEN LEN(phonenumber)
     WHEN @ColumnnName = 'email' THEN LEN(email)


End
from Patients p Cross Apply ( SELECT MAX(ModifiedAt) AS ModifiedAt FROM POI2Version7.dbo.ResultsSTored rs  WHERE  rs.RowId = p.RowId) r
WHERE   p.ModifiedAt > r.ModifiedAt  and  
(case when @ColumnnName = 'firstname' then firstname 
            when @ColumnnName = 'middlename' then middlename 
            when @ColumnnName = 'lastname' then lastname 
            when @ColumnnName = 'State' then [State] 
            when @ColumnnName = 'City' then City 
            when @ColumnnName = 'StreetName' then StreetName 
            when @ColumnnName = 'StreetType' then StreetType 
            when @ColumnnName = 'patientnickname' then patientnickname
            when @ColumnnName = 'patientsMaidenlastname' then patientsMaidenlastname
            when @ColumnnName = 'fathersFirstName' then fathersFirstName
            when @ColumnnName = 'fatherslastname' then fatherslastname
            when @ColumnnName = 'mothersfirstname' then mothersfirstname
            when @ColumnnName = 'motherslastname' then motherslastname
            when @ColumnnName = 'mothersMaidenlastname' then mothersMaidenlastname
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'citizenship' THEN citizenship
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'nationality' THEN nationality
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'Ethnicity' THEN Ethnicity
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'race' THEN race
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'religion' THEN religion
           WHEN @ColumnnName = 'primarylanguage' THEN primarylanguage
           WHEN @ColumnnName = 'patientmrn' THEN patientmrn
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'hospitalname' THEN hospitalname
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'Medicaidid' THEN Medicaidid
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'pcpnpi' THEN pcpnpi
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'phonenumber' THEN phonenumber
            WHEN @ColumnnName = 'email' THEN email





            end) LIKE + '%' + SUBSTRING(@parameterFromUser, @counterOuter, @counter) + '%' 
end
set @counter = @counter + 1
end
set @counterOuter = @counterOuter + 1 
end

Insert into @Matches(RowId, PercentMatch, Percentage) 
select rownumber, MatchingPercent, MatchingPercent * @constantVal
from (
  select t.[Row] as rownumber,
cast(Max(Counts) as float)/(Abs(Max(Counts) - case when Max(VarLength) >= @tempint then Max(VarLength) else @tempint end) + Max(Counts))* 100 
As MatchingPercent
from @Temp t 
Group by Row ) s
select RowId,Percentage from @Matches
End
Go
```

**Edit 2 :** OutputProcedure: This is the procedure that calls a procedure called `Calling procedure` which in turn calls service broker to execute SP's in asynch.

======================================================================

```
Create Procedure OutputProcedure
 @FirstName nvarchar(20) = null,
 @MiddleName nvarchar(20) = null, 
 @LastName nvarchar(20) = null, 
@Date int = null,
@Month int = null,
@Year int = null,
@SSN1 nvarchar(3)= null, 
@SSN2 nvarchar(2)= null,
@SSN3 nvarchar(4)= null,
@ZIP nvarchar(10)= null,
@StateOfResidence nvarchar(2)= null,
 @City nvarchar(20) = null,
@StreetName nvarchar(20)= null,
@StreetType nvarchar(20)= null,
@BuildingNumber int= null,
@Aptnumber nvarchar(10)= null,
@patientNickName nvarchar(20)= null,
@patientMaidenLN nvarchar(20)= null,
@FatherFN nvarchar(20)= null,
@FatherLN nvarchar(20)= null,
@MotherFN nvarchar(20)= null,
@MotherLN nvarchar(20)= null,
@MotherMaidenLN nvarchar(20)= null,
@Citizenship nvarchar(20)= null,
@Nationality nvarchar(20)= null,
@Ethnicity nvarchar(20)= null,
@Race nvarchar(20)= null,
@Religion nvarchar(20)= null,
@primarylanguage nvarchar(20)= null,
@patientmrn nvarchar(128) = null,
@hospitalname nvarchar(30)= null,
@Medicaidid nvarchar(10) = null,
@pcpnpi nvarchar(10) = null,
@phonenumber nvarchar(128) = null,
@email nvarchar(30) = null

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON 
declare  @cnt float(2) = 0, @searchNumber int = 0

select @searchNumber = NEXT VALUE FOR  OutputProcedureCounter
print (@searchNumber)

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##Temp2') Is not null
Begin
drop table ##Temp2
End

create table ##Temp2
(
Rownumber int not null,
ValFromUser nvarchar(20),
Percentage decimal(18, 4) not null
)


--declare @constVal decimal(18,4) = 0
declare @checkbool int
declare @StringConcat nvarchar(600) =  ISNULL(@firstname, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@middlename, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@lastname, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@City, '') + '~' + Cast(ISNULL(@Date, '') As nvarchar(2)) + '~' + Cast(ISNULL(@Month, '') As nvarchar(2)) + '~' + Cast(ISNULL(@Year, '') As nvarchar(4)) + '~' + Cast(ISNULL(@SSN1, '') as nvarchar(3)) + '~' + Cast(ISNULL(@SSN2, '') As nvarchar(2)) + '~' + Cast(ISNULL(@SSN3, '') As nvarchar(4)) + '~' + Cast(ISNULL(@ZIP, '') as nvarchar(10)) + '~' + ISNULL(@StateOfResidence, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@StreetName, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@StreetType, '') + '~' + Cast(ISNULL(@BuildingNumber, '') As nvarchar(10)) + '~' + Cast(ISNULL(@AptNumber, '') As nvarchar(10)) + '~' + ISNULL(@PatientNickName, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@MotherMaidenLN, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@FatherFN, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@FatherLN, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@MotherFN, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@MotherLN, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@MotherMaidenLN, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@citizenship, '') +'~' + ISNULL(@Nationality, '')  + '~' + ISNULL(@Ethnicity, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@Race, '')  +'~' + ISNULL(@religion, '')  + '~' +  ISNULL(@primarylanguage, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@patientmrn, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@hospitalname, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@medicaidid, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@pcpnpi, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@phonenumber, '') + '~' + ISNULL(@email, '')

if exists(select 1 from dbo.ResultsStored where Hashedkey = HashBytes('MD5', @StringConcat))
begin
set @checkbool = 0
--if exists(select 1 from ResultsStored rs join POI2Version7.dbo.Patients p on rs.rowId = p.rowId where p.ModifiedAt > rs.ModifiedAt)
if exists(select * from Patients p Cross Apply ( SELECT MAX(ModifiedAt) AS ModifiedAt FROM ResultsSTored rs  WHERE  rs.RowId = p.RowId) r
WHERE   p.ModifiedAt > r.ModifiedAt)
begin

print 'begin exists'
set @checkbool = 1
Exec CallingProcedure @FirstName = @FirstName,
 @MiddleName = @MiddleName, 
 @LastName = @LastName , 
@Date = @Date ,
@Month = @Month,
@Year = @Year ,
@SSN1= @SSN1, 
@SSN2 = @SSN2 ,
@SSN3 = @SSN3 ,
@ZIP = @ZIP ,
@StateOfResidence = @StateOfResidence,
 @City = @City ,
@StreetName =@StreetName,
@StreetType = @StreetType,
@BuildingNumber= @BuildingNumber,
@Aptnumber = @Aptnumber,
@patientNickName = @patientNickName ,
@patientMaidenLN = @patientMaidenLN,
@FatherFN = @FatherFN,
@FatherLN = @FatherLN,
@MotherFN  = @MotherFN ,
@MotherLN = @MotherLN,
@MotherMaidenLN = @MotherMaidenLN,
@Citizenship  = @Citizenship ,
@Nationality = @Nationality,
@Ethnicity = @Ethnicity ,
@Race  = @Race ,
@Religion = @Religion ,
@primarylanguage = @primarylanguage,
@patientmrn = @patientmrn ,
@hospitalname = @hospitalname ,
@Medicaidid = @Medicaidid,
@pcpnpi= @pcpnpi ,
@phonenumber = @phonenumber ,
@email = @email,
@checkbool = @checkbool,
@cnt = @cnt output 

print 'updating results table'
Update dbo.ResultsStored 
set dbo.ResultsStored.FinalSearchSeral = @searchNumber, 
    dbo.ResultsStored.ModifiedAt = getDate(), 
    dbo.ResultsStored.PercentMatch = t.Perc 
from 
    dbo.ResultsStored
join
    (select Rownumber,(SUM(Percentage) / @cnt) as Perc 
     from ##Temp2 
     GROUP BY Rownumber) t
on dbo.ResultsStored.RowId=t.Rownumber
   and dbo.ResultsStored.HashedKey = HASHBYTES('MD5', @StringConcat)
   end
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..dbo.##Temp2') Is not null
Begin
PRINT 'DROPPED'
DROP TABLE ##Temp2
End
select * from dbo.ResultsStored where dbo.ResultsStored.HashedKey = HASHBYTES('MD5', @StringConcat) order by FinalSearchSeral desc, PercentMatch desc



end

 else if not exists(select 1 from dbo.ResultsStored where Hashedkey = HashBytes('MD5', @StringConcat))
begin
print 'insert record';
set @checkbool = 0;
Exec CallingProcedure @FirstName = @FirstName,
 @MiddleName = @MiddleName, 
 @LastName = @LastName , 
@Date = @Date ,
@Month = @Month,
@Year = @Year ,
@SSN1= @SSN1, 
@SSN2 = @SSN2 ,
@SSN3 = @SSN3 ,
@ZIP = @ZIP ,
@StateOfResidence = @StateOfResidence,
 @City = @City ,
@StreetName =@StreetName,
@StreetType = @StreetType,
@BuildingNumber= @BuildingNumber,
@Aptnumber = @Aptnumber,
@patientNickName = @patientNickName ,
@patientMaidenLN = @patientMaidenLN,
@FatherFN = @FatherFN,
@FatherLN = @FatherLN,
@MotherFN  = @MotherFN ,
@MotherLN = @MotherLN,
@MotherMaidenLN = @MotherMaidenLN,
@Citizenship  = @Citizenship ,
@Nationality = @Nationality,
@Ethnicity = @Ethnicity ,
@Race  = @Race ,
@Religion = @Religion ,
@primarylanguage = @primarylanguage,
@patientmrn = @patientmrn ,
@hospitalname = @hospitalname ,
@Medicaidid = @Medicaidid,
@pcpnpi= @pcpnpi ,
@phonenumber = @phonenumber ,
@email = @email,
@checkbool = @checkbool,
@cnt = @cnt output 
select SUM(Percentage) as SUM , @cnt as Count , (SUM(Percentage)/@cnt) as Percentage from ##Temp2 group By RowNumber order by Percentage desc
Insert into dbo.ResultsStored( searchSerial,FinalSearchSeral, StringSearched, RowId,PercentMatch, HashedKey) 
select @searchNumber, @searchNumber,  dbo.encrypt(@StringConcat), RowNumber, (SUM(Percentage)/@cnt) as Percentage , HASHBYTES('MD5', @StringConcat)
FROM ##Temp2 GROUP BY RowNumber
select * from dbo.ResultsStored order by ModifiedAt desc, PercentMatch desc
end

end
```

Comment: What do you mean by inconsistent results? There's nothing magical about calling stored procedures from service broker, so I'd chalk up whatever symptoms you're seeing to something else.

Comment: By inconsistent I meant that I get different results with same data. i otherwise have no doubt about the script as it works pretty fine without using service brokers. Just that those procedures are executed one by one and here with Service brokers in asynch.

Comment: That probably is because since all these stored procedures access a common stored procedure which is calculating results . Do you mind if I post the code of common stored procedure here ? @BenThul

Comment: Go ahead and edit you question with your procedure definition.